# How to Clear/Reset formData() using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using formData for Ajax Image Uploading, when I am submit first time it will successfully upload, and again click post button that image also posted to server, I think formData will not clear.

My Code

```
$("#postsubmitimage").click(function () {
                var formData = new FormData();
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    if (files[i].type.indexOf('image/') === 0) {
                        formData.append("files", files[i]);
                    }
                }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/Ajax/Fileupload/',
                        data: formData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (json) {
                            $('#textpostimage').val('');
                        }
                    });
            })
```

Comment: you have **initialized the formData** every time. So formData will be clear. Can you please check **file length**. Whether it's cleared after submit the images.

Comment: empty the form before submiting the form again.keep this  formData.empty(); before forloop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happens because your `files` variable is not cleared after the ajax submission. In your click handler you create an empty `FormData` object indeed, but then you proceed to fill that object with old references from `files`, which apparently are not clear.

What I suggest is doing some cleanup after a successful ajax completion

```
success: function (json) {
    // Supposing #textpostimage is your file input, you are already clearing it
    $('#textpostimage').val('');
    // Also clear your "files" reference
    files = [];
}
```

To clear the whole form you could do `$('#myForm').get(0).reset()`

I don't know at what time you populate `files` with values from `#textpostimage`, but make sure to do it not only on page load, if you want to have multiple form submissions working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it this way?

`var formData = new FormData($('<form></form>'));`